# Oracle ADF EAR 11.1.1 requires EAR 5.0?

Tags: eclipse, ear, oracle-adf

I am trying to create a new Oracle ADF application in Eclipse, as soon as I type the application name, an error show in the top of the dialog saying :
Oracle ADF EAR 11.1.1 requires EAR 5.0

and the Next and Finish buttons are disabled .

I am using :
oepe_12.1.1.0.1
Oracle Weblogic Server 12c(12.1.1)

your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ADF 11g on WLS 12c - switch to using WLS 11.1.1.* to match your ADF version.

Answer (score 2):

oepe_12.1.1.0.1 is misleading in its version numbering as - for at leaqst when you build ADF applications- is based (and requires) on WLS 10.3.6 (note there is no WLS version 11.1.1.*).

Frank